# .ajaxForm passing data to php

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, ajax

I'm struggling to pass data using ajaxForm to my PHP file so I can insert into a MySQL database.

Below is the JavaScript function which currently displays a progress bar during form submitting, the problem is the 'post' of name, phone and email don't work but the attachment upload does.

```
$(function() {
    var name = document.getElementById("name").value;
    var phone = document.getElementById("phone").value;
    var email = document.getElementById("email").value;

    var percent = $('.percent');
    var bar = $('.bar');

    $('form').ajaxForm({
        dataType:  'json',
        data : {
                name:name,
                phone:phone,
                email:email
                },

        beforeSend: function() {
            document.getElementById("bar").style.backgroundColor="rgb(51,166,212)";
            bar.width('0%');
            percent.html('0%');
        },

        uploadProgress: function(event, position, total, percentComplete) {
            var pVel = percentComplete + '%';
            bar.width(pVel);
            percent.html(pVel);
        },

        complete: function(data) {
            document.getElementById("bar").style.backgroundColor="rgb(185,221,111)";
            percent.html("Done!");
            setTimeout(function(){
                modal.style.display = 'none';
                location.reload(); 
            }, 2000);

        }

    });

});
```

Here is the code from the PHP file the values are to be passed to.

```
<?php
include("sql_connection.php");

  $name = $_POST['name'];
  $phone = $_POST['phone'];
   $email = $_POST['email'];

$sql = "INSERT INTO helpdesk (Name, Phone, Email) VALUES ($name, $phone, $email)";
mysqli_query( $conn, $sql);

$dir = 'uploads/';
$count = 0;

if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST' and isset($_FILES['files']))
{

foreach ( $_FILES['files']['name'] as $i => $name )
{

    if ( !is_uploaded_file($_FILES['files']['tmp_name'][$i]) )
        continue;

    if( move_uploaded_file($_FILES["files"]["tmp_name"][$i], $dir . $name) )
        $count++;
}
}

  echo json_encode(array('count' => $count));

?>
```

Any advice?

Thanks

Comment: values must be in quotes in your insert query It would be `$sql = "INSERT INTO helpdesk (Name, Phone, Email) VALUES ('".$name."', '".$phone."', '".$email."')";
`

Comment: Thanks, such an easy answer. It now inserting rows into my table but all the values are blank. Any idea why?

Comment: Just add `type: "POST",` in your ajax

Comment: It works if I change var name = document.getElementById("name").value; to var name = "test";. I was wondering if that is because the variable has already been set onload?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All, thanks for your help, the SQL query was in fact wrong but I also needed to use a function for each variable to return its current state before posting.

Thanks

```
    $('form').ajaxForm({
        type: 'POST',
        dataType:  'json',
        data : {
                name:function () {
                        return name = document.getElementById("name").value;
                    },
                phone:function () {
                        return phone = document.getElementById("phone").value;
                    },
                email:function () {
                        return email = document.getElementById("email").value;
                    }
                },
```

Answer (score 1):

Change your SQL query to:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO helpdesk (Name, Phone, Email) VALUES ('".$name."', '".$phone."', '".$email."')";
```

otherwise you need to change your include at the top where you start your database connection.

As I read in your comment the problem is that possibly the inputs doesn't contain any value. When are you launching the Ajax request? After a submit or on page load?

Maybe you can add the code where he should take his information from?

Answer (score 0):

Missing type param in $.ajax

```
$('form').ajaxForm({
    type: 'POST',
    dataType:  'json',
    data : {'name':name,'phone':phone,'email':email},
......................................
```